# how sum data attribute total price?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have select boxes, and they have data attribute (data-price). I want to sum selected option "data-price" as "total" . but I have one problem. If I select only value="bmw" or I have not selected anything it gives me  `NaN$`.

```js
$('#mark, #series').on('change', function() {
  var $selected = $('#mark, #series').children(":selected");
  var sum = 0;

  $selected.each(function() {
    sum += $(this).data('price');
  });

  $('#total').html(sum + '$');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mark" name="mark">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option value="bmw" data-price="200">bmw</option>
  <option value="audi" data-price="400">audi</option>
</select>

<select id="series" name="series">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option value="series-1" data-price="2000"  >3 series</option>
  <option value="series-1" data-price="3000"  >5 series</option>
</select>

<div id="total"> </div>
```

Comment: `$(this).data('price')` will return string. You have to convert it.

Comment: i didn't understated you answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use a fallback value of `0` if the returned value is `undefined`.

using the line.

```
sum += $(this).data('price') || 0;
```

Note: You also need to run this validation function at the beginning to ensure, the result is calculated at the beginning before the `change()` event.

```js
function validate(){
  var $selected = $('#mark, #series').children(":selected");
  var sum = 0;

  $selected.each(function() {
    sum += $(this).data('price') || 0;
  });

  $('#total').html(sum === 0 ? '' : sum + '$');
}
validate();

$('#mark, #series').on('change', function() {
  validate();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mark" name="mark">
          <option value="">--</option>
          <option value="bmw" data-price="200">bmw</option>
          <option value="audi" data-price="400">audi</option>
        </select>

<select id="series" name="series">
          <option value="">--</option>
          <option value="series-1" data-price="2000"  >3 series</option>
          <option value="series-1" data-price="3000"  >5 series</option>
        </select>

<div id="total"> </div>
```

Comment: when i have nothing chose  it gives me   0$, how hide this. if i did not have select  "mark"  display nothing

Comment: @Geo1313 I have used a ternary if to check for this condition, please see my updated answer!

Comment: if i add other select how can  i sum 3 select

Comment: Naren Murali   - can you see this 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47741943/how-sum-data-attribute-3-different-total-price

Answer (score 1):

You must to parse your data which is seen as a string

```
 $selected.each(function() {
     var data = $(this).data('price');
     if(data != undefined){
           sum += parseFloat(data);
     }
 });
```

Comment: This is not the problem. The result would still be NaN.

Answer (score 1):

When you select only one option the selected option of the other does not have a 'data-price' attribute:

```
<option value="">--</option>   <!-- data-price === "undefined" -->
```

You could set a default of "0" to the initially selected option:

```
<option value="" data-price="0">--</option>
```

Example:

```js
$('#mark, #series').on('change', function() {
  var $selected = $('#mark, #series').children(":selected");
  var sum = 0;

  $selected.each(function() {
    sum += $(this).data('price');
  });

  $('#total').html(sum + '$');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="mark" name="mark">
  <option value="" data-price="0">--</option>
  <option value="bmw" data-price="200">bmw</option>
  <option value="audi" data-price="400">audi</option>
</select>

<select id="series" name="series">
  <option value="" data-price="0">--</option>
  <option value="series-1" data-price="2000">3 series</option>
  <option value="series-1" data-price="3000">5 series</option>
</select>

<div id="total"> </div>
```

Comment: when i have nothing chose  it gives me   0$, how hide this. if i did not have select  "mark"  display nothing

Comment: `if (sum === 0) { $('#total').hide() } else { $('#total').show() }`

Answer (score 1):

This code will fix your problem:

```
    $('#mark, #series').on('change', function() {
  var $selected = $('#mark, #series').children(":selected");
  var sum = 0;

  $selected.each(function() {
    var price = $(this).data('price');

    if(price){
        sum += $(this).data('price');
    }
  });

  $('#total').html(sum + '$');
});
```

If you log the `price`variable into the forEach loop, you can see that it returns an `integer` and then an `undefined`. That should be fixed! :)

Answer (score 1):

When you change one dropdown, let's say Make, `$selected` will include two elements:

`<option value="bmw" data-price="200">bmw</option>` and `<option value="">--</option>`

When you are now calculating the sum, you are adding two values `200` and and empty string as strings. You should try to parse all values to integers with `parseInt("string", 10)` (Note the 10 parameter which specifies the base to be used, it's good practice to be explicit, see [parseInt documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) here).

Also, as other answers here state, you should always try to default to an integer value (in the case of the empty string). So your code could now be like this:

```js
$('#mark, #series').on('change', function() {
  var $selected = $('#mark, #series').children(":selected");
  var sum = 0;

  $selected.each(function() {
    var optionPrice = parseInt($(this).data('price'), 10) || 0;
    sum += optionPrice;
  });
  
  $('#total').html((sum) ? (sum + '$') : '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mark" name="mark">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option value="bmw" data-price="200">bmw</option>
  <option value="audi" data-price="400">audi</option>
</select>

<select id="series" name="series">
  <option value="">--</option>
  <option value="series-1" data-price="2000"  >3 series</option>
  <option value="series-1" data-price="3000"  >5 series</option>
</select>
<div id="total"> </div>
```