# how sum data attribute 3 different total price?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have selected option and it do sum of value with data attribute. 
it sum #mark1 + #series1 + #mark2 + #series2

```js
function validate() {
  var $selected = $('#mark1, #series1,#mark2, #series2').children(":selected");
  var sum = 0;

  $selected.each(function() {
    sum += $(this).data('price') || 0;
  });

  $('#total').html(sum === 0 ? '' : sum + '$');
}
validate();

$('#mark1, #series1,#mark2, #series2').on('change', function() {
  validate();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="mark1" name="mark1">
              <option value="">--</option>
              <option value="bmw" data-price="200">bmw</option>
              <option value="audi" data-price="400">audi</option>
  </select>

  <select id="series1" name="series1">
              <option value="">--</option>
              <option value="series-1" data-price="2000"  >3 series</option>
              <option value="series-1" data-price="3000"  >5 series</option>
  </select>
  <select id="mark2" name="mark2">
              <option value="">--</option>
              <option value="bmw" data-price="200">bmw</option>
              <option value="audi" data-price="400">audi</option>
  </select>

  <select id="series1" name="series2">
              <option value="">--</option>
              <option value="series-1" data-price="2000"  >3 series</option>
              <option value="series-1" data-price="3000"  >5 series</option>
  </select>

  <div id="total1"> </div>
  <div id="total2"> </div>
  <div id="total"> </div>
</form>
```

how can i do that,  total1 give total sum  mark1 and series1 ,   total2 give total sum  mark2 and series2 .
total give total sum mark1 ,  series1, mark2, series2

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer help you?

We can simple extract the id number from the id attribute and display in the corresponding div with id `total`. Please let me know if you face issues during implementation!

```js
$('#mark1, #series1, #mark2, #series2').on('change', function() {
  var $selected = $('#mark1, #series1,#mark2, #series2').children(":selected");
  var sum = 0;
  var id = $(this).attr("id")[$(this).attr("id").length - 1];
  $selected.each(function() {
    sum += $(this).data('price') || 0;
  });

  $('#total'+id).html(sum === 0 ? '' : sum + '$');
  var total = 0;
  sum = 0;
  $("div[id*=total]:not(#total)").each(function(){
    $(this).each(function() {
      var val = $(this).text().replace("$", "") || 0
      sum += val * 1;
    });
  });
  $("div#total").html(sum === 0 ? '' : sum + '$');
}).trigger("change");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="mark1" name="mark1">
              <option value="">--</option>
              <option value="bmw" data-price="200">bmw</option>
              <option value="audi" data-price="400">audi</option>
  </select>

  <select id="series1" name="series1">
              <option value="">--</option>
              <option value="series-1" data-price="2000"  >3 series</option>
              <option value="series-1" data-price="3000"  >5 series</option>
  </select>
  <select id="mark2" name="mark2">
              <option value="">--</option>
              <option value="bmw" data-price="200">bmw</option>
              <option value="audi" data-price="400">audi</option>
  </select>

  <select id="series2" name="series2">
              <option value="">--</option>
              <option value="series-1" data-price="2000"  >3 series</option>
              <option value="series-1" data-price="3000"  >5 series</option>
  </select>

  <div id="total1"> </div>
  <div id="total2"> </div>
  <div id="total"> </div>
</form>
```

Comment: no  like this  :  total1  =  mark1 + series1 ;   total2 = mark2 + series2    ;  total = mark1 + series1 + mark2 + series2

Comment: must be 3 totoal sums  <div id="total1"> </div> <div id="total2"> </div> <div id="total"> </div>

Comment: and i have mistake in code  <select id="series1" name="series2">  must be  <select id="series2" name="series2">

Comment: @Geo1313 Updated my answer, please use this code as reference and build your design!

Comment: @Geo1313 Did this help you?