# How to sum data attribute total price from looped select options?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, loops

I found this topic which is so close to my case: 
[how sum data attribute total price?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47572227/how-sum-data-attribute-total-price)

Where:

```js
function validate(){
    var $selected = $('#mark, #series').children(":selected");
    var sum = 0;

    $selected.each(function() {
        sum += $(this).data('price') || 0;
    });

    $('#total').html(sum === 0 ? '' : sum + '$');
    }
        validate();

    $('#mark, #series').on('change', function() {
        validate();
    });
```

and:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mark" name="mark">
    <option value="">--</option>
    <option value="bmw" data-price="200">bmw</option>
    <option value="audi" data-price="400">audi</option>
</select>

<select id="series" name="series">
    <option value="">--</option>
    <option value="series-1" data-price="2000"  >3 series</option>
    <option value="series-1" data-price="3000"  >5 series</option>
</select>

<div id="total"></div>
```

Theses code work exactly the way I want, however, in my case the select options are actualy a loop of selects:

```php
for ($i = 1; $i <= $DayCountValue; $i++) 
    echo "<div class='col'><select name='tour" . $i . "[]' id='tour" . $i . "' class='form-control' onChange='tour_price" . $i . "(this.value), tour_name" . $i . "(this.value), tour_description" . $i . "(this.value);'>";
    echo "<option value=''>Select</option>";

    mysqli_fetch_assoc($tour_check);
    foreach ($tour_check as $tour) {

        echo "<option value='" . $tour["price_id"] . "' data-picture='" . $tour["thumbnail"] . "' data-price='" . $tour["price"] . "'>" . $tour["name"] . "</option>";

                }        
        echo "</select></div>";
```

How can I let the javascript code to fetch values from each selected option? i tried using `this` but it didn't work.

Kind regards,

Comment: `$("select[id^='tour']")` would be a start.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, changing the Javascript code to:

```
function validate(){
    var $selected = $("select").children(":selected");
    var sum = 0;

    $selected.each(function() {
        sum += $(this).data('price') || 0;
    });

    $('#total').html(sum === 0 ? '' : sum + '$');
}
validate();

$("select").on('change', function() {
    validate();
});
```

Where I could take values from each `<select>` in the document.